# Raspberry-pi reboots constantly after programmed reboot

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, reboot

We have a raspberry-pi running a python WSGI. There is a daily reboot schedulled in cron:

```
0 9 * * * reboot
```

The raspberry is configured for starting in **read only mode**.

When the reboot happens while we are in **write mode** for updating software, the raspberry enters in a loop rebooting every minute. If we manage to connect before the next reboot and change again to **write mode**, then this behavior stops.

Why is this happening and how can be avoided?

Comment: How does it get the time? Does it have the correct time? A drift-file?

Comment: It gets the time when it connects to a network I guess, to a default NTC server. The time is correct yes.

Comment: maybe you could check uptime first, and bail out if too young?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the cause of the problem, a partial solution and a complete solution but involves buying hardware for the raspberry.

### The problem

The instant of the reboot, the system wrote the current timestamp as the last valid time. This is possible only when we set the write mode. After the reboot, the raspberry uses the last valid time as the current time, while it is not able to get the real time from a NTC server. As the boot is schedulled for this time, the device reboots again.

Setting the raspberry in write mode before the next reboot was fixing the issue if a new time was available to write before the reboot.

### Partial solution

Instead of using reboot, use shutdown -r to delay the time of the reboot.

```
0 9 * * * shutdown -r 5
```

This will avoid writing the schedulled time of the reboot.

### Complete solution

Buy a NTC module for raspberry, so the device knows the real time at anytime.